# Problem in decrypting a pdf.p7m file with the Bouncy Castle library c#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, .net-core, bouncycastle

I have "translated" java code in c # for the dercrypt of a pdf file. I don't understand why when I start a new CmsEnvelopedData object, I get an exception: "Attempted to read past the end of the stream". I also tried to download the Bouncy Castle sources without installing the NuGet package, but I couldn't figure out what the problem might be. Thanks to those who will help.

Code Java:

```
 public final synchronized byte[] decryptData(byte[] cipherData, String pwd)
    throws CSException 
{

    cipherData = Base64.decode(cipherData);

    PrivateKey privKey = null;

    privKey = loadKeyFromPKCS12( this.encPrivateKeyId, pwd);

    try
    {            
        CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData = new CMSEnvelopedData(cipherData);
        RecipientInformationStore  recipients = envelopedData.getRecipientInfos();
        Collection  c = recipients.getRecipients();
        Iterator    it = c.iterator();

        if (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            RecipientInformation   recipient = (RecipientInformation)it.next();

            this.outputBuffer = recipient.getContent(privKey);
        }
        else{
            this.outputBuffer = null;
        }
    }

    return this.outputBuffer;        
}
```

Code C#:

```
  public byte[] DecryptFile(byte[] file)
    {


        var fileDecode = Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders.Base64.Decode(file);

        CmsEnvelopedData envelopedData = new CmsEnvelopedData(fileDecode);

        RecipientInformationStore recipients = envelopedData.GetRecipientInfos();
        var c = recipients.GetRecipients();
        foreach (RecipientInformation recipient in c)
        {
            var decrypted = recipient.GetContent(RetrievePrivateKey());
            return decrypted;


        }

        return null;
    }
```

Method C# for reading the private key:

```
 private RsaKeyParameters RetrievePrivateKey()
    {

        var obj = AppConfiguration.GetBasePath();
        var path = obj.BasePath + obj.KeystoreFolder;
        var keyfolder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!keyfolder.Exists)
        {
            keyfolder.Create();
        }
        X509Certificate2 certi = new X509Certificate2(path + obj.KeystoreFile, "Password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

        RSA crypt = certi.GetRSAPrivateKey();

        var Akp = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(certi.PrivateKey).Private;

        return (RsaKeyParameters)Akp;
    }
```

Exception returned when I attempt to instantiate a new CmsEnvelopedData object:
[image]

I also enclose the encrypted example file used in the example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkwovnifpjf1xza/offer.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Wait, are you trying to decrypt an actual PDF file directly through CMS? The PDF may *contain* signed or encrypted data, but a PDF does not confirm to the CMS specification (or it would not open with a PDF viewer). I'm not going to "execute" an untrusted PDF file on my computer, thank you very much.

Comment: It is a file that has been digitally signed and encrypted. Don't worry, I'm looking for a solution and not "infecting" people!

Comment: The file I downloaded as first encoded as base 64. It then seems to contain a lot of data in OCTET STRING after decoding that, but I have the feeling that the file was cut short as `openssl asn1parse` fails as well. Maybe your IT dept thought it would be useful to perform FTP-then-copy, without any clear indication when FTP finishes transfer. In my case double embarrassing as I told them that would fail and that they should not come to me with partial files when it did. It did, they came to me. Also beware of text file transfer and such.

Comment: If it is not PDF, then don't call it PDF.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the file extension.
However, probably the file is interrupted before its end because it has been badly copied.

Comment: Certainly looks that way. The exceptions and errors seem to point that out, although to be honest, neither of them is overly specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to decrypt a partial file. The file you showed was a single line base64 string. When decoded, it resulted into an ASN.1 encoded file with lots of OCTET STRING values. The exception you get is when you try and read an ASN.1 encoded binary value, but the stream ends before it can be fully retrieved. This commonly is because the tail of the file is missing, but it could of course also be an indication of a file that is altered, e.g. when line endings are converted in a binary file, or if transmission caused a (nowadays unlikely) error.

The tail of the file is often missing because the file is copied or moved before it is fully received. E.g. if you use an FTP server, it may be hard to tell when a file upload has completed.